# A word for a sudden shift in a song's complexity

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, music

Is there a noun associated with the part of a song where the instruments drop away very suddenly, with the purpose of creating suspense? To give you an example, I'm referring to moments like the one featuring from 1:19-1:23 in the Batman version of 'Something in the Way'. Here, many of the instruments suddenly stop playing, but you get the sense they're about to start up again. I considered 'diminuendo' but as far as I'm aware that implies a gradual softening, whereas the shift in the above example is actually rather abrupt.

'The [insert word] lasted only a few moments before the instruments rushed back in all at once.'

Thanks.

Comment: You would do better to ask this on http://music.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I just listened to that song at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fVeI5xcnsd8, and there was no remarkable change from 1:19 to 1:23. Can you clarify, e.g. with a link?

Comment: Isn't the musical direction *tacit*, no accompaniment? I hear it at 1:50.

Comment: Are you asking for the musical term (which is probably "GP") or a descriptive English term?

Comment: Thanks, @Robusto. I didn't even realise there was a separate section for music. I'll go post this question there now. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan, sorry, this is a different version to the one I listened to. I'll try to find it and then edit it into this comment.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan This is the version I was listening to. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y_PCjw5WKpo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After heading over to music.stackexchange, I've been informed the answer to this question is 'break', which means when all or most of the instruments drop out, usually before a climactic moment. A 'rest' is when an individual instrument plays, is silent, then plays again.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not a very good definition of "rest".  A musician would not say that they had stopped playing and started again when there is a short rest in the middle of a melody. Also an instrument playing a series of staccato notes is literally silent between such notes but those silences are not rests.

Comment: Fair enough @nnnnnn. Would you agree that 'break' is the definition I'm looking for though? The definition I pasted in for 'rest' came from the same contributor.

Comment: I think "break" is the best word for your example, although note that sometimes when people say "break" they mean a "solo break" or "lead break" in which one instrument is actively playing, not just sustaining the last chord like in your example.

Answer (score 1):

**Fermata** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermata))

> (music) The holding of a note or rest for longer than its usual
> duration; also the notation of such a prolongation, usually
> represented as a dot with a semi-circle above or below it, written
> above or below the prolonged note or rest.

**Rest** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rest))

> (music, countable) A pause of a specified length in a piece of music.

Edit: There is a word [which may not be (or may be) relevant to music] and means 'abrupt silence in speech'.

**Aposiopesis** ([Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aposiopesis)) (rhetoric) An abrupt breaking-off in speech, often indicated in print using an ellipsis (…) or an em dash (—).

Comment: These are specific musical terms that do not relate to what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @Robusto the OP was considering diminuendo- a technical musical term so I don’t understand why you think they don’t want one of these.

Comment: @DaleM - These specific musical terms don't fit what the OP described.

Comment: @DaleM: Diminuendo doesn't work either. You can have a diminuendo by the entire orchestra without abruptly going quiet and featuring a small section. What OP seems to be asking about is more like the opening to Beethoven's 7th Symphony. Only, you know, in a Nirvana context.

Comment: @Robusto I’m nit arguing these are the right terms, I’m just saying that there probably is a correct technical musical term and that this would answer the OP